# Java lambda expression best practices

Tags: java, lambda

Java stream operators can sometimes become very cumbersome and hard to debug. Is there a best practice guideline as to how complex your lambda expression should be beyond which it is better to write an elaborate multi-statement piece of code?

For example, I came across below two statement code for finding factorial which was hard to understand:

```
Stream<Pair> allFactorials = Stream.iterate(
  new Pair(BigInteger.ONE, BigInteger.ONE),
  x -> new Pair(
    x.num.add(BigInteger.ONE),
    x.value.multiply(x.num.add(BigInteger.ONE))));
return allFactorials.filter(
  (x) -> x.num.equals(num)).findAny().get().value;
```

Comment: What is your problem statement? What do you need to achieve here?

Comment: You can always create a method that returns the lambda and that way you can add semantics to the stream and simplify the code at the same time, at least for reading purposes (which seems to be what you're looking for).

Comment: @Ravindra: I was trying to revise my Java concepts for an interview and came across this tutorial where this was used as an example for lambda expressions. My question is if this code is a good use of lambda expressions? If not, what are the best-avoided scenarios when using lambda?

Comment: Nope. This example is pure "how *not* to do it". For an interview, it is nice if you know your language well enough to find such "clever" solutions, for day-to-day practice you will be fired/not hired for writing unmaintainable code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java streams are not a silver bullet and you don't have to use it everywhere. There are a lot of cases where you could solve the problem using standard `for` loop approach.

As for your code.. It is a good example where streams complicate the code and make it hard to understand/maintain. But still there are few solutions are more readable.

Take a look:
[calculating factorial using Java 8 IntStream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28484544/calculating-factorial-using-java-8-intstream)

Comment: _Java streams are not a silver bullet_ +1