# Calculate Factorial using Lambda Expressions

Tags: java, lambda

I am a beginner in java trying to find out if there is a way to calculate factorials using lambda expressions. In other words, what i need to do is modify the fatt operator so that the program outputs the factorial number.

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class TestOperator {


    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Stack<Operator> expression = new Stack<>();

        expression.push(s -> 2);
        expression.push(s -> 3);
        expression.push(s -> 1);
        expression.push(s -> s.pop().apply(s) + s.pop().apply(s));
        expression.push(s -> s.pop().apply(s) * s.pop().apply(s));

        System.out.println(expression.pop().apply(expression)); // prints (1 + 3) * 2 = 8


        // rewrite the operator **Fatt** in order to calculate the factorial


        Operator fatt = (s -> { 

            s.pop().apply(s);

            return 42;

        });

        expression.push(s -> 2);
        expression.push(s -> 3);
        expression.push(s -> 1);
        expression.push(s -> s.pop().apply(s) + s.pop().apply(s));
        expression.push(fatt);
        expression.push(s -> s.pop().apply(s) * s.pop().apply(s));

        System.out.println(expression.pop().apply(expression));
        // it should print fatt(1+3)*2 = 48

    }
}
```

I think i should use the for loop, but i don't know how i should apply it using lambda expressions. The exercise says that it can also be done using recursion.

Any help will be helpful

Thanks

Comment: Well do you know how to implement the factorial without the context of the stack evaluation? Like just a static method `public static int factorial(int n)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28484544/calculating-factorial-using-java-8-intstream/28484576

Comment: Does this answer your question? [calculating factorial using Java 8 IntStream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28484544/calculating-factorial-using-java-8-intstream)

Answer (score 1):

Using `for` loop:

```
public long factorialByForLoop(int value) {
    long result = 1;
    if (value == 0) {
        System.out.print(value);
    } else {
        result = value;
        System.out.print(value);
        for (long i = value - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            System.out.print(" * ");
            result *= i;
            System.out.print(i);
        }
    }
    System.out.print(" = " + result);
    return result;
}
```

Using `recursion` algorithm:

```
public long factorialByRecursion(int value) {
    long result = value;
    if (value == 1) {
        return value;
    } else {
        return value * factorialByRecursion(--value);
    }
}
```

Comment: @alex108 If you got the right answer then you should mark this as correct answer for future readers. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class FactorialWithLamda {
  public static void main(String[] args){
  BigInteger number = BigInteger.valueOf(21);
  System.out.printf("%d! = %d%n", number, factorial(number));
}
  
public static BigInteger factorial(BigInteger n){
  return Stream.iterate(BigInteger.ONE, i -> 
      i.add(BigInteger.ONE)).
       limit(n.longValue()).
        reduce(BigInteger.ONE, BigInteger::multiply);

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class TestJava {


    @FunctionalInterface
    public interface FactorialFunc<T> {
        T calc(T t);
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() {

        FactorialFunc<Integer> factorial1 = (n) -> IntStream.rangeClosed(1, n).reduce(1, (i, j) -> i * j);

        Integer v = 0;
        System.out.println(String.format("Factorial of: %d is %d", v, factorial1.calc(v)));
        v = 5;
        System.out.println(String.format("Factorial of: %d is %d", 5, factorial1.calc(v)));

    }

}
```